# Can I display the add content form as accordion

Tags: entities

In Drupal 10, can the add content form for a content type be set up to show groups of fields under expandable sections?

We have tried to make this work with the Field Group module but the removal of jQuery from Core means the accordion feature doesn't work as expected (and adding jQuery UI creates conflicts with our Bootstrap 5-based custom theme)

Either an accordion view or an expanded content view (as Drupal uses on the Extend page with the "Core", "Chaos Tools", etc. sections) would work for this case.

Comment: This is called "Details" in field group module and works in every browser without javascript.

Answer (score -2):

You can use field group module, but don't use the accordion feature, use the HTML element to add the div, classes and whatever you need to get the HTML right, then use https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/accordion/ classes.